# How can I fix that the links have too much height and align the listed items horizontally to match the same level?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

Been trying for hours to fix this yet I don't know what's causing the problem cause I didn't give the links or the listed items any height but when I get rid of the `img` they are fine but when I put it back everything gets messed up. Can someone help me to fix this

[image: Heres the picture]

where the listed items aren't aligned and the link/listed items have too much height which made no sense to me, This is my first time posting

```css
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
    outline:none;
}
body{
    background-image:linear-gradient(147deg,#000428,#004e92);
    height:100vh;
}

header{
    min-height:5vh;
}
nav{
    display:flex;
    align-content:center;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
#Logo{
    width:22vh;
    height:22vh;
}
ul{
    margin-right:23vh;
    width:70%;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-content:center;
    display:flex;
}

a li{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:60%;
    color:#54041c;
    font-size:3.5vh;
    font-family:Verdana;
}
```

```html
**Html Part**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- header-->
    <header>
        <nav>
            <img id="Logo" src="Logo.png">
            <ul>
                <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Clubs</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>About</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- -->
    <main>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `a` must be *inside* `li` because `ul` is only allowed `li` children. Fix that first, then recheck. **Never** go with invalid markup.

Comment: yea, also don't leave the href empty (use href="#!" if you want to prevent it from sending you to another page). Basically change all 4 menuitems to `<li><a href="index.html">ITEM</a></li>`. I think that solves your problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Alignment problem

Flexbox uses `align-items` for the wanted purpose, but you used Grid's `align-content`. Since `align-items` is not set, it defaults to `stretch`, which results in the behaviour you see. Using the correct property will center the elements along the cross axis:

```css
.correct {align-items:center}
.incorrect {align-content:center}

/* Ignore; for a "beautiful" presentation */
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: .8rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
}
div>:nth-child(even) {background-color: #e0e0e0}
div>:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #f4f4f4}
header {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: large;
}
section {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>With <code>align-items</code></header>
  <div class="correct">
    <span>A<br>Very<br>Tall<br>Element</span>
    <span>Num. 1</span>
    <span>Num. 2</span>
    <span>Num. 3</span>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <header>With <code>align-content</code></header>
  <div class="incorrect">
    <span>A<br>Very<br>Tall<br>Element</span>
    <span>Num. 1</span>
    <span>Num. 2</span>
    <span>Num. 3</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Since you used `align-content` on both `nav` and `ul`, the anchors are stretched to the height of the image.

You also set `margin-top` on `li`, which is dependent on the width of the parent element (and can only be used on block-level elements, which `li` by default is). Since the parent element's width is larger with more text-content, elements with more text thus have a larger `margin-top` value:

```css
span {margin-top:10%}

/* Ignore; recreating your situation */
body {display:flex}
span {display:inline-block}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Short text.</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>This is a very long text that will increase the <code>margin-top</code> value.</span>
</div>
```

Fixing the mentioned issues should make your HTML/CSS look similar to this:

```css
nav {display: flex}
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Ignore; recreating your situation */
img {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
li {background-color: white}
nav {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src>
  <ul>
    <!-- <a> inside <li> instead of the other way around. More on this later! -->
    <li><a>Home</a></li> 
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
    <li><a>About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

## The other CSS bits

I recommend using [logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties) where applicable, so in case users translate your webpage to a language of a different text-direction, the layout will follow.

### Viewport units

As of now, you use [viewport-units `vw`/`vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#relative_length_units) to set the size of `img`, the height of `header`, the margin of `ul`, and even the font-size of `a li`! This makes your header scale in a rather incoherent and (warning: opinionated) unsightly way.

I recommend using `rem`, as it is not dependent on the viewport, but *is* dependent on the user's zoom-level. This way, you can more easily guarantee that the final result a user will see is actually what you had in mind, and *still* allow users to change the font-size (which directly depends on the zoom-level) if it was too small for them.

Also, currently `margin-right` on `ul` uses `vh`, making a horizontal length dependent on the vertical viewport unit, which seems confusing. Perhaps you meant to use `vw` (though I still recommend `rem`). Regardless, as you use Flexbox, `margin-right` is redundant as none of its flex-children can grow (you didn't declare them to).

### The issue with `outline: none`

Removing the outline on *every* element [results in **bad accessibility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline#accessibility_concerns)! Users that navigate your page with their keyboards won't be able to see what element they have currently in focus. If you remove the outline, you need to make the focussed element noticeable in another way, for example with `box-shadow` or changing `background-color`.

## HTML

As others have already mentioned: You should always write correct HTML! In your case, these are the specifications you went against:

- `ol` and `ul` may only have `li` or *script-supporting elements* as children.
- `li` may only be used as a child of `ol`, `ul`, and `menu`.

Not conforming to the specification may result in unwanted behaviour, and the browser will try to fix the HTML as best as it can, which may result in a different [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) depending on the browser.

`a` elements can however not have the `href` attribute, regardless if others disagree. In case it does not, the element represents ["a *placeholder* for where a link may otherwise have been placed"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).

Your `img` does not have its `alt` attribute specified, which again [results in **bad accessibility**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#alt). Without it, assistive technology won't be able to understand/announce it properly. If your image is *purely presentational,* consider adding the attribute `role="presentation"` to it. However, most logo-images are not actually presentational. In this case, a short explanation of the image is recommended, for example "Logo of *website's name*".

---

Generally, if you wish to learn more about accessibility, I highly recommend the learning guides regarding accessibility from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility), [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility), and [W3](https://www.w3.org/WAI/fundamentals/accessibility-intro/). Generally (and if you're into this), I also recommend at least occasionally looking up definitions in the official specifications, for example in [HTML's Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/), [CSS' many specifications](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs.en.html), or (if you use it) [ECMAScript's specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/) (JavaScript's specification).

Answer (score 1):

`margin-top: 60%`: If you inspect all four elements with the browser tools / layout tab you'll see that not only the fourth item, but *all* items have a *different* margin-top and therefore vertical position. The reason is that the percentage value for `margin-top` is calculated from the actual *width*  of that item, and the word "Contact" is perceiveably longer than the other three, which causes the different vertical position.

What you can do instead: use `top:40%;` – or whatever value you like (try different ones to find what you want), and that also requires `position: relative;` to have an effect at all. Or you can use a pixel value, as suggested in a previous answer. The snippet below contains the `top:40%;` and  `position: relative;` solution:

```css
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style:none;
    outline:none;
}
body{
    background-image:linear-gradient(147deg,#000428,#004e92);
    height:100vh;
}

header{
    min-height:5vh;
}
nav{
    display:flex;
    align-content:center;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
#Logo{
    width:22vh;
    height:22vh;
}
ul{
    margin-right:23vh;
    width:70%;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-content:center;
    display:flex;
}

a li{
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    top:40%;
    color:#54041c;
    font-size:3.5vh;
    font-family:Verdana;
}
```

```html
**Html Part**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- header-->
    <header>
        <nav>
            <img id="Logo" src="Logo.png">
            <ul>
                <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Clubs</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>About</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- -->
    <main>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This did not solve the issue of the links (`a`) having "too much height". Good explanation of `margin-top`.

Comment: @OskarGrosser The "too much height" is obviously referring to the vertical position of the links. So the percentage value for `margin-top` *is*  the reason for that (the links *are*  vertially aligned in my snippet).

Comment: "Too much height" is referring to the `a` elements _stretching_ as high as the image is. If you inspect your anchor-elements, you will see that they _still_ stretch that high. You have only aligned the `li` elements, which reside _inside_ the `a` elements, but **they are not the links**.

Comment: @OskarGrosser Obviously the OP wants some vertical offset here, that's the only way I can interpret the `margin-top` settings in the question, and therefore I also interpret the "too much height" as referring to the (different) vertical position of the links